# Image transformation based on 3 points

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, image-processing

I want to transform (translate, rotate and scale) an image based on 3 points identified on both overlapping images. Based on the pixel coordinates of the 3 points I want to create a large tiff which merges the two. For the next overlap i want to do the same etc. untill I get a large tiff which combines all the pictures. It's a bit like georeferencing but without the coordinates being used. The problem is I have no experience matplotlib. 
So far i have created a script which shows each couple of overlapping images side by side and when i close the window the next couple opens etc. I have also managed to get the pixel coordinates from clicked points on these images. But now I have to start the transformation based on the 3 points and I just don't know where to start. Any help on usable functions etc.?

EDIT: the images are low resolution thermal images so i don't think automatic transformations will work

Comment: I'm assuming you need to do some math with the raw data, probably using something like `numpy`

Comment: OpenCV is what you're looking for. I dont remember exact functions, but if you know 3 points on both images it can calculate affine transformation (translate+rotate+scale, do not mistake with perspective which requires more points) and transform an image and overlay it over a target image all in one line.

Comment: @IcedLance thanks a lot mate, will look into it!!

Comment: @OferSadan maybe at a later point in the process I'll be able to use it but for the transformation it doesn't seem the right library. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `wand` which is a Python binding to **ImageMagick**. So, start with this image:

[image]

We can distort the red vertex (138,80) to the top-left corner, the green (43,22) to the bottom-left and the blue (49,125) to the bottom right like this (the image is 152x152):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from wand.image import Image

# Open image and distort, giving start x,y and end x,y for 3 points
with Image(filename='start.png') as img:
    points = (138, 80, 0, 0,        # Red vertex
               43, 22, 0,152,       # Green vertex
               49,125, 152,152)     # Blue vertex
    img.distort('affine',points)

    # Save result
    img.save(filename='result.png')
```

[image]

---

You can do just the same thing in Terminal from the command-line too:

```
magick start.png -distort affine "138,80 0,0 43,22 0,152 49,125 152,152" result.png
```

**Keywords**: Image processing, Python, distort, distortion, affine transform, transformation, scale, rotate, ImageMagick.

Comment: Looks very promising, I'm going to give it a try as well! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have a question if I translate the coordinates in from a small range  e.g. 1,1 to  a larger one e.g. 40,40; will it fill in the lower values with a nodata value like 0? That is what I need. The picture might make it easier to understand: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TIv31ws0-k05vSIXYV8vwTqwYQMIaqKl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean. I provided the code so maybe just try it - ImageMagick is installed on most Linux distros and is available for free on macOS and Windows. Or add your images into your question so I can try whatever it is you want to do. Thank you.

Comment: In Imagemagick, you can control the pixel values that are outside the input image as they are transformed to the output using -virtual-pixel xxx. You have many choices: color values or duplicate or mirror or tile, etc. for how to fill the missing data in the output.

Comment: You can also do affine transformations from 3 points in Python/OpenCV. See https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html